# Android Aidl error sdk build tools 29.0.0

Tags: android, aidl

I upgraded my Android app to start using SDK 29 and build tools 29.0.0.
When compiling in Android Studio I get an error:

*Process 'command 'C:\Users\ma_fo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\29.0.0\aidl.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value -1073741819*

The actual command executed for aidl is 
*C:\Users\ma_fo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\29.0.0\aidl.exe with arguments {  -pC:\Users\ma_fo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-29\framework.aidl -oE:\Work\McDevelopment\android-sales-app-webview\app\build\generated\aidl_source_output_dir\debug\compileDebugAidl\out -IE:\Work\McDevelopment\android-sales-app-webview\app\src\main\aidl -IE:\Work\McDevelopment\android-sales-app-webview\app\src\debug\aidl -IC:\Users\ma_fo.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\c21a47fa6bee4a2c237691438c7b1f92\aidl -IC:\Users\ma_fo.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\87cbfb92509988fa6d22255a681cc703\aidl -IC:\Users\ma_fo.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\4cdb3bb0ddd100ba4f9a12ec5a9fae60\aidl -dC:\Users\ma_fo\AppData\Local\Temp\aidl367254395093906008.d E:\Work\McDevelopment\android-sales-app-webview\app\src\main\aidl\com\android\vending\billing\IInAppBillingService.aidl}*

When I run this command manually in an MS-DOS prompt with aidl of build-tools 28.0.3, the compilation passes without any errors.

When I run this command with the aidl of build tools 29.0.0 I get an error:
*aidl E 06-08 18:07:03  4920 13216 io_delegate.cpp:141] Error while creating E:\Work\McDevelopment\android-sales-app-webview\app\build\generated\aidl_source_output_dir\debug\compileDebugAidl\out\E:: Invalid argument*

I would expect the manual idl compilation to work for both versions. Is there are problem with the aidl in build tools 29.0.0 ? Or is there something else which I should update ?

Comment: version 29.0.1 has solved this problem.

Comment: In version 29.0.2 the problem is still present and it reproduces (for me) in 29.0.1

Answer (score 5):

In my case the *.d file in the -d parameter has a error in the first line.

From build tools 28.0.3:

```
C:\[PROJECT-PATH]\app\build\generated\aidl_source_output_dir\debug\compileDebugAidl\out\com\android\vending\billing\IInAppBillingService.java : \
```

From build tools 29.0.0

```
C:\[PROJECT-PATH]\app\build\generated\aidl_source_output_dir\debug\compileDebugAidl\out\C:\[PROJECT-PATH]\app\src\main\aidl\com\android\vending\billing\IInAppBillingService.java : \
```

But I have no solution. I think it is a bug in the build tools 29.0.0.

Update: The build tools version 29.0.1 has solved this problem.

Answer (score 4):

It's a known issue which supposedly have been fixed, but it's not:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132344897

Comment: still present in 29.0.1 and 29.0.2

Answer (score 2):

If you got an error after upgrade (like me), then the solution is downgrade. I downgraded from 29.0.0 to 28.0.3 and it works for me:

```
C:\>"c:\Users\Plinio\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager" --list --verbose

. . .

Installed packages:=====================] 100% Computing updates...
--------------------------------------
build-tools;29.0.0
    Description:        Android SDK Build-Tools 29
    Version:            29.0.0
    Installed Location: c:\Users\Plinio\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\29.0.0

. . .

Available Packages:
--------------------------------------

. . .

build-tools;28.0.1
    Description:        Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.1
    Version:            28.0.1

build-tools;28.0.2
    Description:        Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.2
    Version:            28.0.2

build-tools;28.0.3
    Description:        Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
    Version:            28.0.3

build-tools;29.0.0
    Description:        Android SDK Build-Tools 29
    Version:            29.0.0

. . .

C:\>"c:\Users\Plinio\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager" build-tools;28.0.3
C:\>"c:\Users\Plinio\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager" --uninstall build-tools;29.0.0
```

Before to downgrade, I tried to check this issue. If you notice, there is an "E:" at the end of the path. It looks like a bug of aidl.exe if there isn't an output file assigned as second parameters.

```
aidl.exe [OPTION]... INPUT [OUTPUT]
```

Check your error message (like the mine):

```
aidl E 06-08 18:07:03 4920 13216 io_delegate.cpp:141] Error while creating E:\Work\McDevelopment\android-sales-app-webview\app\build\generated\aidl_source_output_dir\debug\compileDebugAidl\out\E:: Invalid argument
```

Comment: I also had to downgrade, after the latest version also had this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Mine is solved.

Delete all files under this folder:

C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools

VSCode or Android studio will automatically regenerate the files on your local machine during pre-compilation.

Comment: or just delete one with the issue

Answer (score 0):

i met the same issue but use buildTools **version 33.0.0**, after i change it to **version 33.0.1**, these's no issue and build&run app correctly. perhaps it can help who has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `C:\Users\ma_fo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\` and delete the `29.0.0` folder.

then rerun your app it will download the updated version