# Unable to build APK in android studio 3.6.1 getting app:compileReleaseAidl error

Tags: android-studio

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseAidl'.

  > 1 exception was raised by workers:
  >   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\sagar.s.CORP\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\29.0.3\aidl.exe with arguments {-pC:\Users\sagar.s.CORP\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-29\framework.aidl)

Comment: Possible solution is downgrade as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/56677467/14009304